# How do I install distcc?

Tags: debian, archlinux, cross-compilation

I have read [How to build a GCC 4.7 toolchain for cross-compiling?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1/how-to-build-a-gcc-4-7-toolchain-for-cross-compiling) and have successfully built a simple test program that works on my RPi.

To do this, I had to run `arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-gcc hello.c -o hello` on my x86 desktop and `scp` the executable to my RPi. This is slow and a hassle. I would rather control the compilation from my RPi.

I have read about `distcc`, which can be used to distribute the compilation from one machine to another.

How do I install this? I have both Debian/Ubuntu and Arch Linux desktops and both OSs installed on SD cards.

Comment: I've been waiting for someone that's not me to post this question. I really didn't want to do it. Nice work.

Comment: `export DISTCC_VERBOSE=1` Thanks for this !
It is what I'm looking for to debbug my distcc toolchain

Answer (score 12, accepted):

These instructions assume you have a working cross-compiler on the slave. Please read [How to build a GCC 4.7 toolchain for cross-compiling?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1/how-to-build-a-gcc-4-7-toolchain-for-cross-compiling) if you haven't. It is also useful to have `make` installed on the master.

## Installation

First, we must install `distcc`. We shall use the prebuilt packages supplied by the operating systems' package management systems, but you are free to install from source if you want!

### Debian

```
sudo apt-get install distcc
```

### Arch

```
sudo pacman -S distcc
```

## Configuration

### Slave - Debian/Ubuntu

> TODO: Is this the same for Arch? If not, how do we configure Arch?

We need to adjust the settings in `/etc/default/distcc`. In your favourite editor, open it as root; I ran `sudo vim /etc/default/distcc`.

You need to change `STARTDISTCC`, `ALLOWEDNETS` and `LISTENER`. Assuming you have your master and slave are on the same subnet and that subnet is `192.168.0.0/24`, they should be set to

```
STARTDISTCC="true"
ALLOWEDNETS="192.168.0.0/24"
LISTENER="0.0.0.0"
```

Furthermore, you should add the path to your compiler. I did this by adding the following line

```
PATH=$PATH:/home/alex/x-tools/arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi/bin
```

> *Note* The daemon on the slave will be running as the `distccd` user, so ensure the appropriate permissions are configured on your executables; I gave everyone permission to execute.

Run the daemon - it would normally be started at boot - by running

```
sudo service distcc start
```

## Master - Arch

> TODO: Is this the same for Debian? If not, how do we configure Debian?

Open `~/.distcc/hosts` in your favourite text editor and add the IP address of the Slaves. My `hosts` file consisted of a single line, which read `192.168.0.22`.

> *Note* It might be a good idea to assign a static IP address to your slave, otherwise you will have to change this file whenever the IP address changes.

## Use

All going well, you should be able to use distcc quite simply. For example, to compile `hello.c` to `hello.o`, run

```
distcc arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-gcc    -c -o hello.o hello.c
```

### Example: Hello World!

I set up a simple example in my home directory, which consisted of 2 files.

```
# file: Makefile
hello.o: hello.c
hello: hello.o

# file: hello.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  printf("Hello World!\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Running `make hello` will compile locally; you should do this as a quick test first. Go on, I'll wait.

Running `make hello CC="distcc arm-unknown-linux-gnueabi-gcc"` will run a distributed compilation.

> *Note* The preprocessing and the linking still happens on the RPi.

## Debugging

It took me a while to get this working correctly, and the best debugging *tool* I found was a simple environment variable. If you

```
export DISTCC_VERBOSE=1
```

the `distcc` client will output loads of useful information.

This is a long post, so any feedback would be gratefully received. I hope I remembered all the steps!

Comment: Excellent answer. I am going to bookmark this for my RPi development.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain Distcc now supports "pump mode" which allows it to distribute the preprocessing as well.

Comment: @teraquendya They do indeed, I haven't got around to posting details about this yet. I want to make sure I've got everything right without pump mode first.