# Is it possible to cross compile from Arch Linux host with qemu and chroot and how?

Tags: archlinux, cross-compilation, qemu

I was looking [this post](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?p=101026) and trying to make in on my Arch Linux x86_64 host, but without success.

I can't chroot inside and I've noticed that Arch doesn't have qemu-arm-static bins, and it looks that they can't be build because Arch doesn't support any static linking.

So did anyone made it working and how?

Comment: Hello! I did it on Arch linux using and wrote the steps [here](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/286/40).

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer! I tried that but somehow I get bad performance, almost as same as on raspi itself. I am looking to compile some bigger programs so I need cross compiler. Did you got any good performance with that?

Comment: @10robinho Are you using Arch Linux to compile, or are you compiling *for* Arch Linux? What is the OS of the computers being used?

Comment: both Arch Linux, one on x86_64 one on raspi

Comment: You don't want to emulate the CPU with QEMU then. You just want a compiler. There's details of how to set that up [here](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/1144/40). Again my answer is for Arch Linux, but it should be distribution agnostic.

Comment: Thanks, I've realized that, but I'm still unable to compile real programs. Please check this http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/6761/cross-compiling-missing-packages

Comment: Have you solved this issue yet? If so, could you please create a self-answer and mark it as such. We are trying to get the Q:A ratio up and that would help us a ton. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So,

after some time I spent getting my cross-compiling environment ready with Raspberry PI and Arch Linux, I've realized that QEMU is not good solution, for two main reasons:

1. Static linking is not supported with Arch Linux
2. It is slow, so there is no much point in cross-compiling in that way

Solution I decided to use is plain cross-compiling, without any emulators. It takes some time to configure and get used to, but it is definitely worth.