# Cross compiling, missing packages

Tags: cross-compilation, gcc

I've set up a cross compile [toolchain](https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools) for raspberry pi and I can compile basic helloworld and run it on raspberry.

I'm stuck at compiling some open-source programs as `./configure` is complaining about missing packages, for example:

```
configure: No package 'glib-2.0' found
```

I'm using this. `./configure --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf` to cross compile and it looks good until that error above.

Should I tell `./configure` to use libs from target system? How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most setups, everything in your toolchain in configured to use paths relative to your toolchain's compiler. In this case, if you copy for example `arm-bcm2708-linux-gnueabi` directory to `/home/user/`, it will use the directories inside `/home/user/arm-bcm2708-linux-gnueabi` to find appropriate files. For example, it will look for libraries in `/home/user/arm-bcm2708-linux-gnueabi/lib`.

Now if you check, you will find that you actually don't have any libraries in this directory. This is because it's only toolchain that you installed. You need proper libraries in order to compile some complicated software. You should compile needed libraries before you compile the application that you need. If the library that you want to compile uses `autotools`, this in most cases should should be fairly easy, just add `--host=arm-bcm2708-linux-gnueabi --prefix=/home/user/arm-bcm2708-linux-gnueabi` to your `./configure` command.

Since it's not always as easy and your application can have multiple dependencies and each of it's dependencies can have another one's, it will quickly become annoying to this by hand. This is why there are some applications that automates this. One of the simplest is [buildroot](http://buildroot.uclibc.org/). It's usage instructions are unfortunately out of scope of this answer but I'm sure you can find a lot of informations about how to use it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me that. If it looks to directory where toolchain is, could I mount Raspi filesystem to that point so it can use already installed libs? Or I'm missing something again?

Comment: @10robinho: Directly mounting Raspi filesystem on top of that directory is not good idea. You will override it contents this way. Also, you will have some issues with paths since some files in the filesystem are configured for other paths than you have in your toolchain.

Comment: So, there is no way in which I could use raspi filesystem that has already installed needed libs?

Comment: It's not impossible but there is no easy way that I know.

Comment: Another one you can try is [biicode](https://www.biicode.com/), it configures the cross-compiler, compiles the app and sends it to the rpi via rsync