# Are there any `armv6j_hardfp` binary repositories for Gentoo?

Tags: linux

Since the Raspberry Pi hardware is non-ambiguous, the point of compiling optimized to the individual machine is pretty moot, while I'd still like to use Gentoo on my Raspberry Pi due to uts excellent capabilities to compile new software if necessary. So, are there any public binary repositories for `armv6j_hardfp` that spare me from compiling the most common packages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took some digging, but http://tinderbox.dev.gentoo.org/default-linux/arm/armv6j-hardfloat-linux-gnueabi/stable/ seems be the only source available, and it basically seems to provide only the stage3 binaries...

**edit** Now, there's http://gentoopi.technologysecure.com/

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can find out, there is no repository of pre-compiled packages for use with `portage` on Gentoo.

Your best bet would be to install the Raspberry Pi cross-toolchain on a more powerful machine and cross-compile the packages that you need.

You can find information about cross-compiling for the Raspberry Pi in [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/1/40).

Answer (score 2):

Stage-3 for Raspberry 2 and Pi 3 optimised for the NEON hardware acceleration and the newer floating point unit 4. Compiling on the newer Raspberry 2/3, when using an external USB Hardrive is practical.

This page has links and all the important details, [(6) Install Base System - (Stage 3 tarball](http://ukginger.net/Gentoo2/install-pi2too-6-base.html)).

Stage-4 is another story.

For the *original* Raspberry, you would need a Stage 3 [ARMv6 binaries](http://gentoo.org/releases/arm/autobuilds/20160326/stage3-armv6j_hardfp-20160326.tar.bz2), but they would be pretty much identical to Raspbian. I could not recommend compiling on ARMv6 with limited memory its not very pragmatic.

You have to ask, why ?

If you want to run better, faster, binaries than ARMv6 because your hardware supports the new ARMv7 or ARMv8 and has hardware acceleration for audio and graphics - that makes sense. If you own the old original, the best answer is to simply buy a new board for $35.

To find out which cpu type in

cat /proc/cpuinfo

Comment: Good to know, thank you. Note however that this is armv**7**a, so it won't work on a Pi 1