# How to upgrade my Pi to a new major kernel version?

Tags: kernel

I am considering upgrading the kernel of my Raspberry Pi router to 3.19. But how can I do this?

I have found an out-of-tree nl80211-compatible driver for `rtl8188cus` that supports `hostapd` and acs, but it calls for a 3.19 kernel. How do I build this 3.19 kernel, maybe libc, and upgrade my Pi to it?

I have a 20-core server running Ubuntu 14.04 and I have to cross compile using that, or the compiling time will not be tolerable. Please give me instructions on how that is to be done.

**EDIT**: I have not tried to cary this out yet, as I don't have the expertise in debugging such situations (and previous experiences of failed LFS builds left me pretty scarred.) I need some clear instructions on how this should be done, Cross Linux From Scratch style.

Comment: Have you tried? Have you gotten stuck on a particular step? Currently this question is overly broad and may be closed.

Comment: @Jacobm001 No but I am a bit afraid to try it out outright - I am scarred from failed LFS builds.

Comment: Compiling on the pi would probably be quicker than setting up a cross compilation chain if you don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

It is not quite so traumatic as LFS.  The hardest part IMO is getting the cross-compiler set up.   There's already plenty of information about that around, here included;  I recommend crosstool-ng ([here's how I made mine](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/14588/5538)).  Distros including Ubuntu usually have cross-compiler packages, but I believe **they only target ARMv7**, which is fine for the Pi 2 but not previous models.

- Here's an introduction I wrote to [compiling the linux kernel](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/115620/25985) in general.  You don't get the benefit of a bootloader menu on the pi, you have to hardcode which kernel image you want to use with the `kernel=` parameter in `config.txt` on the first partition.
- Here's some [pi specific notes](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/24092/kernel-config-necessary-options) about the kernel, although you should not have to worry much about that if you either:

  - Use the `make ARCH=arm bcmrpi_defconfig` default.
  - Use `/proc/config.gz` as described in the previous link.

  Which you should, because as also mentioned in the previous link, going through all the options takes *hours*.

The actual kernel source for the pi [is here](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/tree/rpi-3.19.y); it is not the vanilla kernel.

Comment: I *did* cross-build a working Cirrus Logic kernel for ARMv6 (as I still have the Wolfson Audio Card I was planning to be used as an oscilloscope) but that was a 3.18.9 - same kernel version as mainline Raspbian. Here I am talking building a 3.19 kernel which is one major version higher than 3.18.

Comment: If you already have a cross-compiler, then that is at of the way.   Using a slightly different version kernel is not a big deal *as long as you remember to install all the modules*, because those must have exactly matching version numbers.

Comment: There are some notes at the end of that crosstool-ng thing about environment variables for cross-compiling the kernel in particular (such as `INSTALL_MOD_PATH`).   You would then copy that whole directory into `/lib/modules` on the pi.

Comment: So the way to build a 3.19.x kernel with the new out-of-tree `rtl8188cus` driver is exactly the same way I built the Cirrus Logic 3.18.9 kernel? (The CL kernel built WM8804 and WM5102 drivers as modules as well. I am actually AirPlay'ing music off my Mac to the Pi now, and the Wolfson sounds really audiophilic.)

Comment: Also, do I need to rebuild `libc`?

Comment: No, you're not rebuilding libc, except for the one the cross-compiler uses if you are building all that from scratch.   The kernel itself is static, and libc's interface with it is stable enough to not worry about; if you had to rebuild libc for the actual system, you might as well scrap it (that is LFS style pain).  With regard to the driver, you build the kernel first, make sure that works, then follow the 3rd party instructions.