# missing crypto kernel module on Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: raspbian, linux, kernel, pi-2, raspbian-jessie

I'm trying to use dm-crypt on my Raspberry Pi 2 with Raspbian (jessie) to open a trueCrypt volume, but i get

```
Required kernel crypto interface not available.
Ensure you have algif_skcipher kernel module loaded.
```

My research has yielded that algif_skcipher should be available since `2.6.38`, but my kernel version is `3.18.11-v7+` (according to `uname`). Why isn't the module available and, more importantly how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

That module is available, but it looks like it was not compiled for the Raspbian kernel; the crypto modules would be in `/lib/modules/3.18.11-v7+/kernel/crypto` but `algif_skcipher.ko` is not there.

It is, however, [in the rpi kernel source](https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux/tree/rpi-3.18.y/crypto), so it could be built.  **You need to match the source used to your kernel exactly,**<sup>1</sup> or else just build a new kernel with that module.  This is not so hard, although it will take a very long time on the pi, which means you have to either be careful to get it right the first time, or else use a cross-compiler.

---

<sup>1. This is not as simple as it sounds, since the source packages in Raspbian are just the plain Debian (non-pi) ones and therefore getting the source to match means doing some careful exploration of the git repo.</sup>

Comment: what do you mean with it takes very long - 10 hour? a day? a couple of days?

Comment: I'm not sure if I've ever tried -- I [cross compile](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/14587/linux-based-cross-compiler) it.   I would think 3-4 hours+; it used to take at least that long on old single core pentiums.  The [last post here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=66&t=7680) looks to be 10 hours -- although another says only 1, I think that is actually recompiling, which can be faster.

Comment: How exactly do I have to match the source to my Kernel?

Comment: See here: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/30204/5538