# Installing ESP8266 SDIO driver; "make" command gives "Kernel build tree not found" error

Tags: raspbian, wifi, kernel, driver

I'm attempting to add a kernel module on a Raspbian Debian installation for an SDIO-based wifi module driver( found here: https://hackaday.io/post/28712)

The stable image comes with kernel 4.1, so first I upgraded the kernel(the uname -r command now reports the kernel version as 4.2.7-v7+).

So I run

git clone https://github.com/al177/esp8089.git
cd esp8089
make

However, the "make" command returns the "Kernel build tree not found" error. The kernel was compiled from source, but can't find the build tree. I'm in a bit over my head with this.

Comment: You not only need the kernel, but you need the kernel source files to compile. check this for the details http://elinux.org/Raspberry_Pi_Kernel_Compilation

Answer (score 1):

The error you're seeing is caused because it's looking for the `build` directory in the kernel source. In the instructions I've linked below, that's step 3.

I have described the steps you need to take here: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/38991/19435 if you have **not** used `rpi-update` to update your kernel.

And that was actually a 'specialized' version of the guide I've written here: https://github.com/diederikdehaas/cknow.org/blob/master/rpi/compile-kernel-module-on-raspberrypi.md which describes the procedure for when you have not used `rpi-update` but also if you have.

The guide assumes you're compiling **on** the RPi, thus no cross compiling.

I realize it's customary to provide at least summary in an answer, but that's not possible. It contains several steps which need to be followed 'to the letter'.

It would've been rather easy if the raspberrypi foundation would provide a `linux-headers-<version>` package, like Debian does, and I've really tried, but thus far unsuccesful.