# Finding a compatible commit of the kernel source files to cross-compile a kernel module

Tags: driver, cross-compilation

1. For Raspberry Pi I used an image from https://www.raspberrypi.com/software/operating-systems/#raspberry-pi-os-64-bit
2. I cloned the entire history from the https://github.com/raspberrypi/linux to the host PC for cross-compilation of the kernel.
3. I checked the kernel version using the uname -a command. The result is:
   Linux raspberrypi 6.6.20+rpt-rpi-v8 #1 SMP PREEMPT Debian 1:6.6.20-1+rpt1 (2024-03-07) aarch64 GNU/Linux

If I found out that the kernel version is 6.6.20+rpt-rpi-v8, how can I find a commit in the cloned repository with the kernel source files that is guaranteed to be compatible with the version used on the Raspberry Pi?

Comment: Look here: https://github.com/raspberrypi/rpi-firmware/commits/master/ you should find the 6.6.20 kernel in that list.

Comment: Thank you. But there must be a general approach, something like:
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/36900/how-do-i-get-the-configuration-and-module-symvers-for-a-raspbian-kernel-to-compi/38991#38991