# How to install a cross compiler for Raspi 2

Tags: raspbian, cross-compilation, ubuntu

I went through hell installing a cross compiler on Ubuntu for my Raspi. Now, I have Raspi2's and I am I am going through it again. Could someone provide instructions here for myself and others who are struggling with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to.  The Pi 2 uses a much more common architecture and the ARM cross-compiler package in Ubuntu will work.  See my [comments here from yesterday](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37393/5538/) for further explanation of that.

You should be able to find the package on Ubuntu with:

```
apt-cache search "cross-compiler" | grep -i arm
```

There may be more than one; you want the "hard float" version, probably called `gcc-arm-linux-gnueabihf`.  This toolchain should then be in path, and the compiler will be called something like `arm-linux-gnu-gcc`; you may have get a clue from `dpkg -l ______ | grep "*/bin/*"` where blank is the name of the package (this lists some of the installed files).

Alternately, since ARMv7 is backward compatible, you should be able to use your old cross-compiler.

Comment: any chance you could give a link to downloading one such cross compiler

Comment: It's a ubuntu package.  I've edited in some stuff about that.