# How to get executable code for raspberry pi from arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc cross compiler

Tags: pi-2

i am using arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc cross copiler for arm but i am not able to select different architecture of this processor. can anyone help me to choose raspberry pi architecture

Answer (score 1):

The one that comes stock on most mainstream linux distros targets ARMv7, and so *should* be okay for compiling code to run on a Pi 2/3 -- although if you are using Raspbian, the fact that it is compiled for ARMv6 may complicate this (but I don't think that is the case).

If you are using any other model, i.e., the original A/B, the A+/B+, or the zero, then you cannot use that compiler and will have to [download](https://github.com/raspberrypi/tools/tree/master/arm-bcm2708) or build one yourself (I recommend [crosstool-ng](http://crosstool-ng.org/) for this purpose as doing it from scratch is quite a task; you will find various tutorial etc. involving `ct-ng` and that Pi, [including here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/14587/5538)).