# apt-get "cannot locate the package"

Tags: linux, apt

I was following a tutorial online so I can install a USB DisplayLink monitor, and it told me to type:

```
sudo apt-get install git-core gcc-4.6-arm-linux-gnueabi
```

I tried that, and it says it "cannot locate the package".
Please help

Comment: I would have made this a comment but I don't have the privileges. Could you explain why you think this is a kernel error? You didn't supply the error message. Are you sure it contains no useful information for anyone reading your question?

Comment: It said that it could not locate the package.  By the way, you now have 56 reputation so you can now comment.

Comment: I've edited the question to remove reference to the kernel, since it is not directly involved.

Comment: Have you run sudo apt-get update lately?

Comment: @RPiAwesomeness actually, that was the first thing I did.

Comment: Just checking. That is quite often the cause of these errors, so I was just playing it on the safe side. I'm gonna look around a bit and hopefully get you an answer :D BTW, what OS are you using? Raspbian?

Comment: @RPiAwesomeness Ok.  The comment section in the tutorial said "You have to be using 12.04 and everything has to be updated. Install or upgrade to 12.04lts and run sudo apt-get update."  12.04?  How do I type that into the console?

Comment: Ah, that means this tutorial was meant for *Ubuntu*. 12.04 LTS is a version of Ubuntu, which came out in April (04) of 2012 (12). That *might* be your issue, though check out Goldilock's answer, it's impressive and well done.

Comment: I kind of thought this might be the case (the instructions are for cross compiling).  Unless the raspberry pi is mentioned explicitly though, I don't think the stock ubuntu arm cross-compiler will work (it targets armv7, not armv6), so you will have to compile right on the pi.  Which is probably easier anyway, although it will be much, much slower.

Comment: @goldilocks Well, it did say raspberry pi in the title.  Here is a link: http://mitchtech.net/raspberry-pi-kernel-compile/

Comment: It's worth a try.  I didn't realize you wanted to do the whole kernel, which apparently takes 5+ hours on the pi (but probably only 5-10 minutes on your desktop).  The kernel is actually one of the easier things to cross-compile because it doesn't have any dependencies.  If it the ubuntu one doesn't work (try a simple "hello world" program first), have a look here: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1/how-do-i-build-a-gcc-4-7-toolchain-for-cross-compiling/225#225

Comment: @AwesomeUser That link is for cross-compiling the kernel for use on the Pi, on an Ubuntu system.

Comment: @RPiAwesomeness which is support to work on Raspbian

Comment: Yes. Have you followed Goldilock's answer?

Comment: @RPiAwesomeness yes, and it said it worked.  Here is a link to the original tutorial I was following. http://imkiyoung.wordpress.com/2012/09/18/raspberry-pi-and-aoc-e1649fwu-usb-powered-led-monitor/

Comment: Glad to hear it :) I have considered doing that project myself, just haven't had the time :P

Comment: @RPiAwesomeness I don't think it completely worked http://tinypic.com/r/99q6wn/8

Comment: "Cross-compiling" refers to compiling an executable for one architecture (e.g., `armv6`, like the pi) on another (e.g., `x86` or `x86_64`, like a normal PC).  So if you are doing the compiling on the pi for the pi, don't use instructions intended for cross compiling!  However, you might want to think seriously about it, because as mentioned, it takes quite a few hours to do the kernel right on the pi, and chances are you will screw it up the first few times, and if each time takes 4 hours...basically unless you are already familiar with the process, it is not very feasible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As RPi Awesomeness points out, run `apt-get update` and then `apt-get upgrade` before you do anything.

`apt-get` is part of the Debian package management system used on, e.g., raspbian.

Unless you are certain of what you want to install, it is usually a good idea to see exactly what is available first.  `apt-cache search` will provide a list matching a string, for example;

```
> apt-cache search git-core
devscripts - scripts to make the life of a Debian Package maintainer easier
git - fast, scalable, distributed revision control system
git-core - fast, scalable, distributed revision control system (obsolete)
```

It's not always obvious why the search returns the things it does, but in any case, here we have confirmation that `git-core` exists and is available, although there is the note that it is obsolete.  We could broaden the seach by using just `git`, but this returns more than 500 results.  However, if we filter via `grep` (see `man grep`), we can apply a [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) so that only packages with "git" at the beginning of their name are returned:

```
apt-cache search git | grep "^git"
```

This limits us to a more manageable 30-40 hits, the first of which is:

```
git - fast, scalable, distributed revision control system
```

That's the package you actually want.  For "gcc-4.6-arm-linux-gnueabi", we could try `apt-cache search gcc | grep gnueabi` -- but that returns nothing.  The same regexp trick might work (just plan `search gcc` will return way too much again):

```
apt-cache search gcc | grep "^gcc"
```

A single screenful, which is easy to glance over.  But there is no mention of "gnueabi".

"arm-linux-gnueabi" is actually a tuple used to identify the target of a compiler.  In this case, the target is the same as the base system, so we can assume that the normal compiler will work in this case (it would have been good if you had included a link to the instructions you are following).  We just need to make sure we get at least version 4.6; the list returned from the last search (which I omitted here) contains reference to 4.4 through 4.7.  As it so happens, the current default on raspbian is 4.6, so just plain:

```
apt-get install gcc
```

Will do it.  Check to make sure afterward with `gcc --version`.  You should see something like:

```
gcc (Debian 4.6.3-14+rpi1) 4.6.3
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: any suggestions now that I gave the link?