# No Screens Found Error

Tags: raspbian, display, xorg

I am trying to get my AOC e1649Fwu USB monitor to work on my Raspberry Pi.  I was following [this](http://imkiyoung.wordpress.com/2012/09/18/raspberry-pi-and-aoc-e1649fwu-usb-powered-led-monitor/) tutorial, and got through all of the steps except building raspberry kernel image. It was discussed [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/15159/apt-get-cannot-locate-the-package?noredirect=1#comment21803_15159) that if I'm "compiling on the pi, for the pi", that I don't want to cross-compile.  I hooked up the data usb to the pi, and the power usb to a Airport Express USB port. [image: setup].  I then typed startx and got an error message that was too big to type, so I used my iPad, and took the following screenshot:
[image]

I have updated, upgraded, checked for typos, and cannot figure out what's wrong.  Please help!

Comment: The error message is unreadable.

Comment: @SteveRobillard yes, I was afraid of that.  I would love to make it in text, but the message is so long.  I am going to try ocr

Comment: @SteveRobillard I used my iPhone, and got better results.  See above.  You may need to zoom in command > + or control > +

Comment: What does the log show?

Comment: A lot!  I am pulling it up now

Comment: I picked up the AOC monitor Did you get this to work?

Comment: The key message there is "no screens found". In general, that message means that either you don't have the correct X driver installed for your video card, or X couldn't figure out what driver to use.   You'll find more information in `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` or `/var/log/Xorg.0.log.old`.

Comment: You can upload long log files to http://pastebin.com and put a link in your post. I'm quite interested to learn about this!

Comment: @Fred I don't have my pi on right now and recently has been crazy for me, but I should get it uploaded soon.  Thanks for pastebin!

Comment: @ken unfortunately no.  Have you tried it?

Comment: @fred sorry, I just reformatted my RPi, until I can find a solution.