# Installing opencv-3.3.0-r5 on Gentoo 64 bit OS at Raspbery Pi 3B+

Tags: pi-3, opencv

My linux environment is

```
pi64 /home/demouser # uname -a
Linux pi64 4.14.31-v8-b36f4e9e1984+ #1 SMP PREEMPT Sun Apr 1 14:15:34 BST 2018 aarch64 GNU/Linux
```

First time, I use Porthole to emerge opencv-3.3.0-r5, but twice stuck at 96%.
Then I use command line

```
# emerge --noreplace media-libs/opencv
```

The error message are as follows:

```
 * Messages for package media-libs/opencv-3.3.0-r5:

 * ERROR: media-libs/opencv-3.3.0-r5::gentoo failed (compile phase):
 *   emake failed
 * 
 * If you need support, post the output of `emerge --info '=media-libs/opencv-3.3.0-r5::gentoo'`,
 * the complete build log and the output of `emerge -pqv '=media-libs/opencv-3.3.0-r5::gentoo'`.
 * The complete build log is located at '/var/tmp/portage/media-libs/opencv-3.3.0-r5/temp/build.log'.
 * The ebuild environment file is located at '/var/tmp/portage/media-libs/opencv-3.3.0-r5/temp/environment'.
 * Working directory: '/var/tmp/portage/media-libs/opencv-3.3.0-r5/work/opencv-3.3.0-.arm64'
 * S: '/var/tmp/portage/media-libs/opencv-3.3.0-r5/work/opencv-3.3.0'
```

Please help. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Could you provide the outputs listed in the error message please so we can try and help? `emerge --info ...` and so on?

Comment: * Package:    media-libs/opencv-3.3.0-r5
    * Repository: gentoo
    * Maintainer: amynka@gentoo.org dilfridge@gentoo.org
[code]  * USE:        arm64 eigen elibc_glibc ffmpeg gtk jpeg kernel_linux opengl openmp png python python_targets_python2_7 python_targets_python3_5 qt5 tiff userland_GNU
 * FEATURES:   preserve-libs sandbox userpriv usersandbox
>>> Unpacking opencv-3.3.0.tar.gz to /var/tmp/portage/media-libs/opencv-3.3.0-r5/work
>>> Preparing source in /var/tmp/portage/media-libs/opencv-3.3.0-r5/work/opencv-3.3.0 ...

Comment: [  8%] Building CXX object modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_core.dir/src/matop.cpp.o
{standard input}: Error: open CFI at the end of file; missing .cfi_endproc directive
{standard input}:938: Error: undefined symbol x used as an immediate value
aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu-g++: internal compiler error: Killed (program cc1plus)

Comment: do you have email, i can send the complete /var/tmp/portage/media-libs/opencv-3.3.0-r5/temp/build.log. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are running out of RAM. Please increase the size of your swap file and try again, or install a binary package instead (e.g. one that you have [cross-compiled](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1/how-do-i-build-a-gcc-4-7-toolchain-for-cross-compiling)).